# In ConTeXt, How can I get in the header (double sided document) the chapter's name in one page and the section name in the next one?

Tags: header-footer, context, double-sided

Also I want chapters always starting on a right page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for example:

```
\language       [en]
\definepapersize[Book]  [width=14cm,height=21cm]
\setuppapersize [Book]  [A4] 
\setuppagenumbering 
   [alternative=doublesided,    
    location={footer,marginedge},
    way=bytext, sectionnumber=no, partnumber=no]
\setuplayout
   [width=11cm, height=16.5cm,
    header=14pt, headerdistance=10pt,
    footer=24pt, footerdistance=0pt,
    grid=yes, marking=on, location=left] 
\setupheadertexts[][chapter][part][section] 

\starttext
\chapter{foo}
\section{bar}
\dorecurse{5}{\input knuth}

\chapter{baz}
\input knuth \input knuth

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]